# Fanatic badge not working

Tags: bug, badges

I tried to get the fanatic badge, i.e. visit the site for 100 consecutive days. When I check the progress on my profile, it tells me that I have 1/100, i.e. I never visited the site on consecutive days. This is not true. Is either the system broken or can fanatic badges not be achieved on beta sites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two caveats with this badge:

- What is considered "a day" is always in UTC and not your local timezone. You can see the current time in UTC in the top-right of the "achievements" menu in the top bar.
- Not all pages count as "a visit":

  [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/166789):

  > login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access"

  [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298532/660921):

  > You need to do more than just load the home page to register as a "visit" for the badge. This may include viewing question pages, your profile etc. It's not guaranteed to be just one of these other pages either. The exact criteria aren't public though, so even if I knew I couldn't tell you.

Since so far [16 people have earned this badge](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic), with the last one just two weeks ago, it looks like the badge is working as such, and you probably tripped over one or both of these caveats... Sorry :-(

Comment: That answers my question. I must have tripped over one of this caveats. Interestingly, the same strategy did work for me on other sites, but not on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fanatic, so you can get fanatic on beta sites. However: you missed quite a few days:

[image]

And since also you missed May 1, the current count of consecutive days is 1: today.

Comment: Thanks! Where do you find that information?

Comment: @pfnuesel in your user page, under the profile tab, click on the "visited X days"